# JavaFX setCursor immediately display

Tags: javafx-2

I need to change cursor on dragging and want to change it after mouse is pressed immediately, so I do it like this:

```
public class Graph extends Pane{


 void someInit(){

    setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                logger.info("pressed graph x-> " + e.getX() + " |  y->" + e.getY());
                setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
            }
        });
 }

}
```

After pressing mouse button and not moving it any pixel, cursor does not change. It changes after smallest mouse move. How can I force to display it immediately without mouse move.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursor is updated immediately when changed via CSS, for example:

```
.moving {
    -fx-cursor: closed_hand;
}
```

Then your code could look like:

```
public class Graph extends Pane{
    void someInit() {
        setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                logger.info("pressed graph x-> " + e.getX() + " |  y->" + e.getY());
                Graph.this.getStyleClass().add("moving");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And you can revert the cursor later in another event using:

```
getStyleClass().remove("moving");
```

Comment: The :pressed CSS selector might also be useful in this situation: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introlimitations

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in JavaFX that is fixed in 8.

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33412